# Redis cache not working with django

Tags: python, django, caching, redis

I have a django project on an ubuntu EC2 node, and I want to set up a cache, I am following http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/07/14/using-redis-as-django-session-store-and-cache-backend/ to use redis for this. In the article the author refers to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/cache/ and based of that I can do:

```
(env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~/projects/tp$ python manage.py shell
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> import django
>>> import redis
>>> from django.core.cache import cache
>>> cache.set('my_key','hi world')
>>> cache.get('my_key')
'hi world'
```

My current django view contains;

```
def index(token):

    html = calculator(token)
    print('here1')

    import redis
    from django.core.cache import cache
    cache.set('my_key', 'hello, world!', 60*60*12)
    print('here2')

    return html
```

However when I trigger the index function, nothing is saved to the cache. I checked after from the command line.

How can I get the cache working?

edit:

```
>>> print(settings.CACHES)
{'default': {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache'}}
```

Comment: What do your CACHES settings look like?

Comment: what is the purpose of "import redis" ? you don't use it below, so your cache settings is important as Daniel said. Print it in both shell and your index function

Comment: from django.conf import settings
    print settings.CACHES

Comment: I've removed "import redis" please see edit

Comment: OK, you're using LocMemCache backend which means that you're using the memory of your Python process to cache data. Which also means that your data will be lost as soon as the process is terminated. Which also means that you're not using Redis

Comment: and 2 process don't share the same memory, so it's not possible to get one cached value from the shell in your Django index function for instance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key point is your CACHES configuration, it should be :

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'redis_cache.RedisCache',
        'LOCATION': '/var/run/redis/redis.sock',
    },
}
```

(cf http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/07/14/using-redis-as-django-session-store-and-cache-backend/)

Comment: and provided you followed the previous steps of this page

Comment: Thank you, I'll make the changes. What did you mean by " it's not possible to get one cached value from the shell in your Django index function " ?

Comment: I assumed that you were using on one side a running Django instance and on the other side a Django shell (both at the same time), in this case, it's 2 different processes <=> different memory space, different caches :)

Comment: yes , I was running them at the same time. If its not the same cache, how do you test at the command line?

Comment: Precisely you need an outer process that is "shared" between process. With Redis, you'll get this. You could achieve the same goal with Memcache (which is more "classical" and easy to set up in django as a backend).

Comment: Thank you, and BTW, I just tested the redis cache from the django shell and saw that it does work now.

Answer (score 1):

Updated version of answer of Raphaël Braud:

```
 'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django_redis.cache.RedisCache',
        'LOCATION': '/var/run/redis/redis.sock',
    },
```